# What tag should be used to identify posts about `Plot` and related functions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There's always been some confusion and lack of clear agreement about what term to use to describe figures that depict the set of points corresponding to a function or relation. Is it a "graph", a "plot", a "figure" — or something else? Given the range of functions Mathematica provides for generating these, whatever they're called, and given the versatility of these functions in generating many related (and not so related) graphics that are *not* strictly mathematical functions or relations, what tag or tags should we use to identify posts discussing them?

Some possibilities include:

- graphics
- plots
- plotting
- graphing
- figures

---

FWIW, Math.SE uses [**graph**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) for "questions regarding graphs of functions"; Stack Overlfow uses [**plot**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot) for "a graphical technique for presenting a data set or a equation" but [**graph**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) for "a graphic (such as a chart or diagram) showing or displaying the relationship between two or more variables".

Comment: I think that we should try to reserve [tag:graph] for graph theory questions. [tag:plotting] and [tag:graphics] should cover most of the other cases.

Comment: @Simon you know I love brevity, but I suspect that even on this new site it may be necessary to use [tag:graph-theory] unless we want to spend extra time retagging.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I agree. I think that was the consensus reached on chat (or somewhere); [tag:graph] will just confuse people, so should probably not be available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was some debate among a few regular users on SO, and I believe the consensus essentially was that a tag like [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) should be used for built-in plotting functions like `Plot` and `ListPlot`, even extending to packages like `ErrorListPlot`, despite the fact that all such functions ultimately produce a `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` objects. For direct uses of `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`, though, the consensus was to use [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). But, I don't think the 3D version was talked about, and I would not have a problem with another tag [graphics3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics3d).

Comment: It could be useful to have graphics3d but it might be better to roll it into graphics while the site is new.

Comment: I like [graphics] for low-level constructions using `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`, and [plotting] for questions involving `___Plot___` functions.

Comment: @BrettChampion, that was pretty much my thinking.

Comment: I also agre with @Brett, so this is cleared up then.  Can we edit tag wikis already?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I think the same requirements for editing apply: they have to be reviewed. But, I don't know by who, in this case. Also, synonyms are off the table until someone breaks 1250 rep.

Comment: @Szabolcs I put something in for the [tag:plotting] wiki.  Not showing up yet, of course...

Comment: @Brett Now it says "edit pending" and I can't suggest any other edits until it gets reviewed.  It's sending me to the review queue, but none of us have enough privileges for that.

Comment: @Szabolcs tag wikis are getting populated now.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that since the main Mathematica function for generating plots is `Plot`, we should use a tag name based on "plot".

`Graphics` is a (related but) separate thing in Mathematica. Typically when you're plotting a function, you're not thinking about the details of the `Graphics` object you get. I would suggest reserving the "graphics" tag for questions related to actual manipulations of `Graphics` objects, not simple plotting. "graphics" would also be suitable for questions that use `Plot` (or a variant) simply as a starting point to obtain a `Graphics` object for further manipulation.

Comment: Actually, all plot functions are just convenient wrappers for `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @rcollyer: This is true but most people treat them as distinct, independent things.

Comment: @MikeBantegui, very true, and that's why I suggested the hierarchy of tags.

Comment: The whole of Mathematica is a convenient wrapper of something. I wouldn't say that Graphics and Plot are the same, since they serve pretty distinct things on the user side.

Comment: @David, they're distinct until you type `Head@Plot[x^2,{x,0,1}]` then they're distinctiveness disappears.