# Almost all Plotting questions are tagged Graphics, also

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently, all but one [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) question is tagged with [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), also. Per the [prior discussion](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/52), I don't think this was what was intended. Is this what we intend to happen, or should the distinction between the two be made more clear?

Answer (score 3):

I think having both [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) makes sense in situations where you're using `Show` or some other method to build upon a built-in `...Plot` function.

(I took [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) off the `RegionPlot` example, where it seemed wholly unnecessary.)

Comment: I was leaning that way, myself, but I wanted the overall discussion, so we can set it in thick-mud, if not stone.

Comment: BTW, I have both [graphics] and [plotting] favorited and will see if I can keep some order to them.  The tag wiki for each could be improved a bit..

Comment: Yeah, have to get to those at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I think of [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) as being the super-tag, with [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting), [image-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-manipulation) being sub-tags. I can also see situations where you would use the [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag but not either of those two, e.g. when the question is about exporting graphics.

Since one can add up to five tags, I think the double-tagging is a reasonable solution.

**EDIT** To clarify, I think of [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) as being a good tag for people to follow when they are looking for questions to answer. I see the narrower tags as being better for looking for existing questions when you are trying to see if your question has already been asked.

Comment: I can see the latter, but the former, while being technically correct, seems like tag pollution to me, and require additional work on the users/mods part to keep correct.

Comment: I just found myself attempting to retag an [tag:image-processing] question. I may lean more your way, then I thought.

Comment: @rcollyer please see my edit