# What are our expectations for the contents of tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I've recently added some content to the tag-wikis, notably to move the contents of [this closed question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/349/mathematica-packages-reference-sorted-by-area-of-research) to [somewhere more appropriate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/package/info).

I have only added material to tag wikis if I thought there was useful material on the internet that I could link to, e.g. the help pages on Wolfram's web site. I have not added Excerpts alone.

What is our expectation of these tag-wikis? I think they could be quite useful and avoid people asking questions to get the same information.

**Should we aim to get decent tag-wikis for the most-used tags before we get to the public beta stage?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often (on SO/SE), people try to summarize the tag's meaning and Wikipedia definition in a tag wiki. This is **not** what a tag wiki should contain. It is rather unfortunate that "wiki" reminds people of Wikipedia, but a tag wiki serves two main purposes:

1. The tag wiki excerpt serves as a short blurb to users as to *what* questions that tag should be used for. Not everyone notices this, but you can hover on tags anywhere and it brings up a pop-up containing the excerpt. So it's good to think of it as a tweet – be to the point and tell them what to use this tag for and what not to use it for.
2. The main body should:

   - go into more detail on the usage of the tag
   - point them to additional tags that they could use. For example, points from [the recent discussion](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/5) on [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) can be included as guidelines (although in general, I'd recommend waiting a bit to see if the discussion is settled).
   - List additional resources, packages (such as the big list question from earlier today)
   - Have a list of frequently asked questions (not to be confused with the site's FAQ and the other faq tab on a tag page). For example, [export](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) could point to questions on how to export and how to get rid of grey edges in polygons when exporting to PDF, etc.
   - Have a list of questions that highlight the best-practices or have canonical answers. These needn't necessarily be frequently asked.

[The Scala tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) on Stack Overflow is a decent example that lists the frequently asked questions, [the food-safety tag](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info) on Cooking is an example of one that educates users and provides tips on the topic and the [baking tag](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/baking/info) guides them on tag usage for alternate interpretations of 'baking'.

It will probably take a while before we accumulate enough questions to know which ones are frequently asked, which one has a better answer, etc., but it needn't be done all at one. We can do it in passes.